# i would like to control one z-wave wall switch with two remote controls

Tags: home-automation

I would like to control one z-wave wall switch with two remote controls.  If there's an issue using two z-wave remotes, then I would like to clone the on and off signal to a second learning RF remote.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clone on and of with a learning remote z-wave has some sort of rotating code I'm sure, just like you can't clone a garage door remote with just the remote.

You should be able to pair a second controller to the network, but I am not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Just buy the Aeon Zwave minimote and pair it to your hub.  You can then program the four buttons on each to control switches.  As far as I know, you can use different remotes to control the same switch.